# How to Forward Emails from Outlook to SharePoint Email Archive using a Outlook Rule

Tags: email-enabled-library

I have created a a doc library in the SP (Email Archive) with an email id attached- 'xxx@apofficemail.ms.com'.

This allows me to directly post emails in the SP.

Thiis is working fine for emails sent directly to this acccount (from my outlook). But to automate this i've set up Outlook rule to forward mails sent to my ID to this account ('xxx@apofficemail.ms.com').

Now, even though i see the mails being forwarded in my Sent Items by the said Rule, they do not appear in the SharePoint Archive.

How do i debug the issue here ?

Comment: Meybe You can do this by worcflow's ?

Comment: Try using redirect instead of Forward, and make sure your list incoming email settings are allowing all senders..

Comment: Were you able to fix it?